# Applying spfont & spcolor without designgallery/Javascript in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-branding

Is it possible to apply spfont, spcolor files to current look & feel without having to visit design gallery - `_layouts/15/designgallery.aspx` -, or code e.g. Javasript; which changes everything including application & system master-page?

Thoughts:
Currently I can think of creating an entry manually in design list - `_catalogs/design/AllItems.aspx` - with a name **Current**, with required masterpage, spfont & spcolor location. I'm looking at more sposphicated way which is more business user friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use Change the look section itself. Below is a smart way!

You'll be needing below:

1. color palette
2. font file
3. master-page with preview file
4. background image

You've color palette, font file & master-page. All you need is a preview file. You can copy seattle's preview file & rename as your-master-page-name.preview. This will ensure you've a entry of your master-page in change the look section. Background-image being optional is not a concern.

This way you could request business user to select appropriate master-page, font & color & apply styling without any custom development.

Note: This will change system master-page as well.

Comment: @Vicky, thank you for the reply. I was looking for more sophisticated option but this is also okay!

Comment: Accepting this answer since couldn't get better answer. I'll look for more answers in future.